# Two function in onMouseOver React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render: function() {

    return (
            <td>
              <img src={this.props.image.path} width="40" height="40" id={this.props.image.id}
              onMouseOver={()=>document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).height="80", ()=>document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).width="80"}
              onMouseOut={()=>document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).height="40", ()=>document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).width="40"}/>
            </td>
        );
    }
```

I want to change image size when onMouseOver but it only width changed. 
How can I use two function in onMouseOver. Thank you.

Comment: removed `HTML` tag as it has nothing to with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it like this:

```
onMouseOver={() => {
    document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).height = "80";
    document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).width = "80";
    }
}
```

But better to use function

```
onMouseOver={this.someFunction}

someFunction = () => {
    document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).height = "80";
    document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).width = "80";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy one. You can define a new function to call them at once.

```
function changeWidthAndHeight() {
  document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).height="80"
  document.getElementById(this.props.image.id).width="80"
}
```

Then, replace the content of onMouseOver with it.

```
onMouseOver={changeWidthAndHeight}
```

Comment: You should use arrow function as per ES6 standard

Comment: I will leave the selection to the questioner

Answer (score 0):

Merge them into 1 function

```
onMouseOver={()=> {
  let obj = document.getElementById(this.props.image.id);
  obj.height="80"; 
  obj.width="80";
}}
```

Or you can make those style a variable then update that using `onMouseOver`.

Comment: This is of course true, but putting lots of logic into an arrow function is not a good habit.

Comment: Yes, but I am following his idea/logical. He has to make it works first then he can try to refactor or make it better later